# php seo friendly url using .htacess is not working i tried in different ways

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wants my website URLs in this format:

```
http://www.myglobeon.com/shop/Heeta_Colection_2023
```

The `.htaccess` file is below, please help.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^shop/([^\.]+)$ shop.php?store=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That looks fine and should rewrite to `shop.php?store=Heeta_Colection_2023`. What's the problem?

Comment: That should work fine. You'll have to adjust your links in your code, though. A `.htaccess` file doesn't update all your links for you, it just makes the new-format links work.